# How to remove default form tag while rendering output in hook_theme

Tags: theming

I am customizing the login form. I have to put all the three forms(login, register, forgotpassword) into one page. 
**I don't want that unwanted root form tag, how can i remove that one? I am using drupal 7.** This is my code.

### template.php

function bartik_theme() {

```
$items = array();

$items['user_login'] = array(
    'render element' => 'div',
    'arguments' => array('form' => NULL),
    'variables' => array('form' => NULL),
    'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'bartik') . '/templates',
    'template' => 'user-login',
    'preprocess functions' => array(
          'bartik_preprocess_user_login'
    ),
```

);

return $items;

}

### user-login.tpl.php

```
        <div id="signupbox">
            <?php
                $login_form = drupal_get_form ( 'user_login_block' );
                echo drupal_render ( $login_form );

                $forgot_password_form = drupal_get_form ( 'user_pass' );
                echo drupal_render ( $forgot_password_form );

                $register_form = drupal_get_form ( 'user_register_form' );
                echo drupal_render ( $register_form );
            ?>
        </div>
```

My problem is that all the 3 forms are rendering in one more form tag.

### My Output:

<form action="/drupal728/user" method="post" id="user-login">

```
 <form>Login</form>
 <form>Password....</form>
 <form>Registration....</form>
```

</form>

I don't want that unwanted root form tag, how can i remove that one? I am using drupal 7.

Answer (score 0):

You're attacking the problem at the wrong level - if you want to modify forms/functionality, the theme layer's too late. Specifically what's happening here is that by default forms have a theme wrapper of `theme_form()` which adds the form tag. The form template itself should only contain the form's children elements. (And shouldn't contain for example calls to `drupal_get_function()`).

Here are some ways of adding the forms:

1. Implement `hook_menu_alter()` and alter the page callback for the login page to be your own callback. This callback returns the three forms. Don't forget to check for whether the user's logged in [like core does](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.pages.inc/function/user_page/7).
2. Create a couple of custom blocks for the other two forms and add them to the login page.
3. Implement [`hook_page_build()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_page_build/7) and add the forms there (quick and dirty!).